# Notation? q(A), where A is a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let $A \in Mat(n,F)$ be a matrix. Consider the set of polynomials $J_A \subset F[t]$ such that $q(t) \in J_A$ if and only if $q(A) = 0.$ Show that $J_A$ is an ideal. The monic polynomial generating JA is called the minimal polynomial of A.

**Question:** What does $q(A) = 0$ mean?

Comment: $q(t) = a_0 + a_1 t + \cdots + a_m t^m\quad\rightarrow\quad q(A) = a_0 I_n + a_1 A + \cdots + a_m A^m$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that when you apply the polynomial $q$ to the matrix $A$ you get the zero matrix.  For example, if $q(t)=t^2$, $r(t)=t^2+1$ and $A$ is the 2x2 matrix with a 1 in the upper-right corner and 0 everywhere else, then $q(A)=0$ and $r(A)=I$.  (Coefficients in the polynomial are interpreted as scalar multiplication by the matrix and the constant term is interpreted as a scalar multiple of the identity matrix.)

Comment: and the ideal is not just the zero polynomial because of Cayley Hamilton. Strange, this OP has linear algebra questions before this one.

Comment: What do you mean? I haven't taken abstract algebra. I'm in a linear algebra course and the professor asked this question. I think I missed the lecture in which he talked about ideals (briefly).

Comment: To show that it is an ideal, I have to show the set is not empty correct? Can I simply point to the polynomial $p(t) = a_0,$ where $a_0 = 0$?

Comment: Well, you weren't asked to show $J_A$ is a non-zero ideal, but the result is much more useful that way.  To show $J_A$ is an ideal you just need to show that it is closed under addition and that multiplication of a polynomial in $J_A$ by ANY polynomial results in a polynomial in $J_A$.  This is easy because $0+0=0$ and $0\cdot g(A)=0$ for any $g$.